# sewn in signatures

Tags: meaning

Example:

> We have made every effort to make this the best book possible. Our paper is opaque, with minimal show-through; it will not discolor or become brittle with age. Pages are **sewn in signatures**, in the method traditionally used for the best books, and will not drop out as often happens with paperbacks held together with glue. Books open flat for easy reference. The binding will not crack or split. This is a permanent book.

What does that really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In publishing, a 'signature' is a group of 32 pages sewn together. These are then glued between the covers of the book. From Wikipedia: "A hardcover, hardbound book has rigid covers and is stitched in the spine. Looking from the top of the spine, the book can be seen to consist of a number of signatures bound together. When the book is opened in the middle of a signature, the binding threads are visible."